# Pacejs radar loader renders wrong

Tags: css

I used to have Minimal style and then I decided to change to Radar. As I can see it renders wrong(see the image) What can cause this problem? I didn't edit css. Just downloaded and included to a page.

http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

[image]

Comment: Did you try loading it on a page by itself? Some of your styles are probably leaking in to the loader.

Comment: @positlabs, oh, the problem was with bootstrap.css. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your styles are probably leaking in to the loader.

You can try loading it on a page by itself to test this.